# tensorflow estimator : different paths of model_fn in training and serving

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

I am coding a tf custom estimator and I want to compile the trained estimator and use it in another application.

In my function `model_fn` I want to have an algorithm during the train/eval/predict loop, and another equivalent algorithm when I compile the `.so` (indeed, some operations I use during training do not have any target ops in the xla framework, so i replace them by equivalent operations after my training is done).

How can this be achieved?